# Could not cast value of type 'to_do_list.AddItemViewController' (0x1009f3970) to 'to_do_list.ListDetailViewController' (0x1009f3850)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I had created a list in which i provided a detail disclosure button for editing the list, but when i clicked on this button it shows me an error

> Could not cast value of type.

Here is my code:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let navigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! ListDetailViewController

    controller.delegate = self

    let checklist = dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]

    controller.checklistToEdit = checklist

    presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: yes I want to share if you can resolve my problem.

Comment: Ok. But reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyse your project and suggest you to remove all unwanted navigation Controllers and add this code in your `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method:

```
let VC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListNavigationController") as! ListDetailViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```